# Default embedded modules in bootx64.efi, grubx64.efi and mmx64.efi

Tags: 20.04, grub2, bash, bootloader

In the default bootx64.efi file present in an Ubuntu image, what are the modules embedded?

I would like to replicate the original bootx64.efi file using the command:

```
grub-mkimage -o bootx64.efi -O x86_64-efi -p /boot/grub <default_modules>
```

What are these <default_modules>?

I would also like to know the default modules in the grubx64.efi and mmx64.efi files.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David 20.04 LTS

Comment: Do not know for a fact, but I believe the bootx64.efi in a full install is just a copy of shimx64.efi. They are both 933.3 KiB in my 20.04 Kubuntu install.

Comment: do you know which modules it contains?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo default_modules are the filesystem modules on your system. the arguments should be `grub-mkimage -o /path/to/mounted/targetOS/efidir/core.efi --format=x86_64-efi '--prefix=(hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub' ext2 part_gpt`.

Answer (score 1):

And, in fact, my reverse engineered answer was a bit off, because of the `strings` command that will only recognize strings larger than 4 characters. The `build-efi-images` in the Ubuntu/Debian source code actually builds grubx64.efi. It can be found at [link]https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2-unsigned/tree/debian/build-efi-images and inside are three variables with module names. Please be aware that these variables do not contain the full list of included modules, because some of these have dependencies.

After fetching the dependencies, the full list of included modules is
`acpi afsplitter all_video bitmap bitmap_scale boot btrfs bufio cat chain configfile cpuid crypto cryptodisk datetime disk diskfilter echo efi_gop efinet efi_uga ext2 extcmd fat font fshelp gcry_arcfour gcry_blowfish gcry_camellia gcry_cast5 gcry_crc gcry_des gcry_dsa gcry_idea gcry_md4 gcry_md5 gcry_rfc2268 gcry_rijndael gcry_rmd160 gcry_rsa gcry_seed gcry_serpent gcry_sha1 gcry_sha256 gcry_sha512 gcry_tiger gcry_twofish gcry_whirlpool gettext gfxmenu gfxterm gfxterm_background gzio halt help hfsplus iso9660 jpeg keystatus linux linuxefi loadenv loopback ls luks lvm lzopio mdraid09 mdraid1x mmap mpi net normal ntfs password_pbkdf2 pbkdf2 pgp png probe procfs raid5rec raid6rec regexp relocator search search_fs_file search_fs_uuid search_label sleep smbios squash4 terminal trig video video_bochs video_cirrus video_colors xfs xzio zfs zfscrypt zfsinfo zstd`. (Missing from my previous answer: `cat, fat, ls, lvm, pgp, png, zfs` - all two or three letters - and their dependencies.)

Answer (score 0):

The list of included modules is gathered at compile time. However, I managed making a list of the grubx64 included modules in Ubuntu 22.04 by reverse engineering:

```
strings /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi|grep -A10 --no-group-separator LICENSE= |grep -v LICENSE=|grep -v '^grub_' |grep -v '^_'|grep -v '^\.'|grep -v '[A-Z]' > /tmp/modulelist
for n in `cat /tmp/modulelist|sort|uniq`; do if [ -f /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/$n.mod ]; then echo $n; fi; done > /tmp/grub-include-these
echo `cat /tmp/grub-include-these` > /root/grub-modulelist
```

So to answer the question ("What are these <default_modules>"): the default modules in Ubuntu 22.04 seem to be: `acpi afsplitter all_video archelp bitmap bitmap_scale boot btrfs bufio chain configfile cpuid crypto cryptodisk datetime disk diskfilter echo efifwsetup efi_gop efinet efi_uga ext2 extcmd font fshelp gcry_arcfour gcry_blowfish gcry_camellia gcry_cast5 gcry_crc gcry_des gcry_dsa gcry_idea gcry_md4 gcry_md5 gcry_rfc2268 gcry_rijndael gcry_rmd160 gcry_rsa gcry_seed gcry_serpent gcry_sha1 gcry_sha256 gcry_sha512 gcry_tiger gcry_twofish gcry_whirlpool gettext gfxmenu gfxterm gfxterm_background gzio halt help hfsplus iso9660 jpeg keystatus linux linuxefi loadenv loopback lsefi lsefimmap lsefisystab lssal luks lzopio mdraid09 mdraid1x memdisk minicmd mmap normal ntfs part_apple part_gpt part_msdos password_pbkdf2 pbkdf2 play priority_queue probe procfs raid5rec raid6rec reboot regexp relocator search search_fs_file search_fs_uuid search_label sleep smbios squash4 terminal test trig true video video_bochs video_cirrus video_colors video_fb xzio zfscrypt zfsinfo zstd`

That's quite a lot, but *not all modules are included*. For example, the `minix` module is not included in grubx64.efi, although it can be found in `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/`.

BTW, I proceeded to build my own grubx64.efi with:

```
grub-mkimage -c /boot/efi/EFI/my-own/grub.cfg -o /boot/efi/EFI/my-own/grub.efi -O x86_64-efi -p grub/ `cat /root/grub-modulelist`
```

... and made it bootable:

```
efibootmgr -v -c -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -l '\EFI\my-own\grub.efi' -L my-grub
```

Please note that I included a grub.cfg file too - a minimal one, that will just search a certain UUID, then load the grub.cfg from there.

The Ubuntu default grubx64.efi also seems to contain a squashfs4 filesystem with a font. Maybe more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).